# How to update UI with a completion block

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, animation, completionhandler

I am using a pod to display images in some page-based view controller. There is a function built into the pod that animates navigating to another photo, but this function does not have a built in completion handler. I was wondering if there was a way I could wrap this function in a completion block, so I can guarantee I execute code after the UI animation has completed. I tried wrapping the function in a `UIView.animate()` block, which kind of worked but made presentation of the animation a little buggy. Thanks!

This is the code I have now:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    if (self.photosViewController.dataSource.numberOfPhotos == 1) {
      // Dismiss view controller
    } else {
      if (currPhotoIndex == 0) {
        self.photosViewController.navigateToPhotoIndex(currPhotoIndex + 1, animated: true)
        currPhotoIndex = 0
      } else {
        self.photosViewController.navigateToPhotoIndex(currPhotoIndex - 1, animated: true)
        currPhotoIndex -= 1
      }
    }
  }) { (completion) in
    art.delete()
  }
})
```

Comment: Which pod are you using? Maybe someone can provide advice specific to that pod.

Comment: I am using the AXPhotosPod @jtbandes. In general, I would like to know how to wrap UI updates in a callback

Comment: In answer to your question, if a framework doesn’t provide some hooks (whether completion handlers, delegate methods or some other mechanism), no, you can’t simply add your own. These hooks have to be integrated into the framework, itself. If not there, you have to modify the framework or find another one.

Comment: By the way, are you talking about [AXPhotoViewer](https://github.com/alexhillc/AXPhotoViewer)?

Comment: Yes :) I am talking about AXPhotoViewer. UIViewAnimate gets close to what I want minus some minor animation glitchiness, would it be bad to use that function?

Comment: If I read it correctly, the idea is that it supports asynchronous image retrieval. Thus, simple UIKit animations are likely to just be the wrong tool. You don’t know when the images are actually downloaded. Now, looking at the README, I wouldn’t be surprised if there are better ways to achieve what you want. There are 83 forks of this library, so you want want to figure out if any of them are actively maintained and post an issue there.